# List index out of range error, but can't see why?

Tags: python, index-error

This is pretty simple, but I can't figure out why I'm getting the 'list index out of range' error. I have a list called 'cycle_entries' and a list called 'rawdates' which both have a length of 132:

```
print len(cycle_entries)
print len(rawdates)
132
132
```

The output of this is also a list of length 132:

```
times = re.findall(dtdict['tx'], str(entries))
print len(times)
132
```

However, when I try to iterate from index [0] to [131] I'm getting an error.

```
for i in range(len(cycle_entries)):
    localtime = rawdates[i]+re.findall(dtdict['tx'], str(entries))[i]
    print localtime

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I can't figure out why, because this works:

```
test = rawdates[131]+re.findall(dtdict['tx'], str(entries))[131]
print test
```

Anyone know why it works normally but I get the error inside the loop?

Comment: what value is `i` when the error occurs? and does the error persist if you move the `findall` operation outside of the loop?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I tried both 0 and 131 and those both worked outside of the loop.

Comment: First, why do you calculate `re.findall(dtdict['tx'], str(entries))` in the loop? It does no change. Calculate it once before the loop starts (as `times`) and use the list in the loop.

Comment: @DYZ tried your suggestion just now, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: you should move `times = re.findall(dtdict['tx'], str(entries))` outside the for loop to compute this once and note 132 times.

Comment: Once you do what I suggested, get rid of `i` entirely: `for r,t in zip(rawdates,times): localtime = r+t; print(localtime)`. No `i` - no problem.

Comment: Thank you, it works now after moving the `findall` outside the loop! I didn't have to remove the `i` either.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your lists contains strings, you can use `zip` function to iterate over both lists simultenously:

```
>>> times = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> rawdates = ['raw1', 'raw2', 'raw3', 'raw4']
>>> for time, rawdate in zip(times, rawdates):
    localt = time + rawdate
    print localt


1raw1
2raw2
3raw3
4raw4
```

Note that both variables are computed before the `for` loop.
You can also use `itertools.izip` which makes an iterator instead of a list.

[Python's zip function docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)